# Twilio TaskRouter: Unable to connect Reservation to Call

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter

I am using TaskRouter Twilio with Laravel.

Here is what I am doing right now

1. I have attached a twiml app to a phone number.
2. Added a webhook to that twiml app.
3. On that webhook I am hitting this code
   $response = new VoiceResponse();

   ```
   $taskAttributes = [
       'channel' => 'voice', // Specify that it's a voice call

   ];

   $enqueue = $response->enqueue('WSDSupport',['workflowSid' => $workflowSid,
                                               'action' => url('ivr/testQueue')]);
   $enqueue->task(json_encode($taskAttributes),['timeout' => 200]);
   return response($response)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
   ```
4. Now on frontend I received the reservation created event (reservation.created)
5. I get a prompt to accept the reservation. When I do.

   ```
   if (confirm('Incoming call. Accept?')) {
                          reservation.accept();
                      } else {
                          reservation.reject();
                      }
   ```

Worker is selected but nothing happens. On the Workflow callback URL I am running this code.

```
 return response()->json([
                 "instruction"=> "dequeue",
                 "from"=> $taskAttributes['from'],
                 "post_work_activity_sid"=> config('services.twilio')['postWorkActivitySid']
             ]);
```

I need to connect my agent via a call to the customer. I have searched everwhere but did not find any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
return response()->json([
            "instruction"=> "dequeue"
        ]);
```

Just return this. This will look for the worker who has accepted the reservation and call that worker contact_uri,

```
contact_uri: '' // This can be the client id which you have used to created the token on client side.
```

which is set in his/her profile on Twilio. It can be a phone number or browser client id.

Answer (score 1):

The [dequeue instruction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls#automatically-bridging-call-to-worker) requires four parameters. Your code sample is missing the "to" parameter:

```
{
  "instruction": "dequeue",
  "to": "{the Worker's phone number, sip uri, or client uri. Required.}"
  "from": "{the caller ID that you want to send to the Worker. Required.}"
  "post_work_activity_sid": "{the ActivitySid that should be assigned to the Worker after the call ends. Optional.}"
}
```

> More about these fields:
>
> **instruction** specifies the assignment activity to perform. Use
> 'dequeue' to dequeue a call to a Worker. For a full list of assignment
> instructions, read about handling assignment callbacks here.
>
> **to** specifies the Worker recipient's phone number.
>
> **from** specifies the caller ID that should be sent when extending the call to the Worker.
>
> **post_work_activity_sid** specifies the ActivitySid that you want to
> assign to the Worker after the call completes. Use this to transition
> your worker to a status that makes sense for their after-call, work
> for example "Wrapping up".

Updated code:

```
return response()->json([
                 "instruction"=> "dequeue",
                 "from"=> $taskAttributes['from'],
                 "to"=> $workersPhoneNumberInE164,
                 "post_work_activity_sid"=> config('services.twilio')['postWorkActivitySid']
             ]);
```

Comment: Tried that. If To is missing then it will take contact_uri params from workers attributes. That is why I removed that for time being.

Comment: Why don't you try adding the To and From parameters directly (not variables) with working values? Then you will know if it is that component or some other area of the code?

Comment: Tried That still nothing.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Twilio Console Error Log or other Logs? This should show where the task is routing and give insights into why the audio cannot be heard.